# React Native get firebase database push token key

Tags: react-native

Here is my reference. Everytime this function is called it in my firebase database it creates a new set of data under a unique token [Like this]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPjEz.png. And i want to get that token.

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref('Products')
    let newProduct = ref.push(newProduct)
    newProduct.set({
        color: color,
        time: Date.now(),
    })
```

Yes! I saw some similar questions like this but none of them couldn't help me.
Some please **helps**
[image: This]

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. Please update your question with more detail.

Comment: It updated it. Please check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#getting-the-unique-key-generated-by-push

```
// Generate a reference to a new location and add some data using push()
var newPostRef = postsRef.push();

// Get the unique key generated by push()
var postId = newPostRef.key;
```

In your current code `newProduct.key` should already be set correctly, I think.